# Clearing the player of an item that does NOT have a custom name on it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working in 1.14 and I have this code: `clear @a minecraft:wooden_sword 1` which is simply clearing the player of any wooden sword that they have in their inventory.  However, I would like this to happen only to any wooden sword that doesn't have a custom name on it.  So if I have a wooden sword called "Test" in the inventory and I run that command on a repeating command block, that particular wooden sword is not cleared from the inventory.  But any sword with the default name Wooden Sword is cleared.

Comment: Could you not just clear wooden swords with the name "Wooden Sword"? Any otherwise named wooden sword would not be cleared and only the ones named with the default name would. Unless default swords don't have a name at all and just display the item name then this would not work I suppose.

Comment: @Nik3141 yes, I have tested this, but it seems that the default name cannot be targeted through commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a data pack for custom crafting. [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Recipe) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Recipe)) is the wiki article for custom recipes. These are made exactly for your usecase and can do everything a normal person would want from a custom crafting system.

I'll answer your question anyway: The problem is that you need to specify every slot. If you also want to replace the unnamed items with ones that have special properties, while keeping the count (useful for shift-clicking in custom crafting), you also need to specify every possible amount. That gives you a total of 2304 commands in the worst case. But you can mainly just copy-paste. There are also some ways to improve performance, if you need that, but it should be ok as it is.
This does not work for arbitrary banner patterns, because you would need to specify more possible combinations than you have hard drive space for.

Here are the commands that replace all wooden swords that are **not** named "a" with wooden swords that are named "b". You can just remove the »`Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"`« part if you want to replace all wooden swords that have no name and no lore.

```
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.0 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.1 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:2b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.2 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:3b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.3 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.4 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:5b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.5 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:6b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.6 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:7b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.7 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:8b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.8 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:9b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.0 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:10b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.1 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:11b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.2 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:12b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.3 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:13b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.4 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:14b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.5 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:15b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.6 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:16b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.7 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:17b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.8 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:18b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.9 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:19b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.10 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:20b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.11 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:21b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.12 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:22b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.13 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:23b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.14 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:24b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.15 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:25b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.16 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:26b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.17 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:27b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.18 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:28b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.19 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:29b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.20 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:30b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.21 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:31b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.22 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:32b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.23 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:33b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.24 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:34b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.25 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
execute as @p if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:35b,id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",Count:1b}] unless data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"a\"}"}}}] run replaceitem entity @s inventory.26 wooden_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}} 1
```

Explanation: For every slot, the corresponding command checks first if you have exactly 1 (in case you want to use different items, you can copy-paste this and change the amounts, otherwise you might as well leave out the »`,Count:1b`« part and the " `1`" at the end) wooden sword in that slot, then it checks if you have **not** a wooden sword with the name "a" in that slot, then it replaces the item. So if you have a wooden sword there which is named "a", nothing happens. And if you don't have a wooden sword there, nothing happens as well.
You can also chain multiple of these `unless data` parts to exclude multiple names.

Comment: I have ~39 custom crafting recipes, will I have to do this with each item since I'm planning for every item to have a custom name/lore? Will I have to have these 35 command blocks for each item?

Comment: 36 and yes. Or just use a data pack with recipes, much easier.

Comment: What do you mean data packs with recipes? That's what I am doing to get the custom crafting to work in the first place.  Is there a way to get NBT data to work with for custom recipes in a data pack because that would be perfect.

Comment: I thought you could, but I just looked it up and apparently you actually can't. That's weird. Then, in afraid, the best option is indeed to have such a system for every item. You can avoid having to list every possible stack number by letting the crafting output always be something unstackable. You can re-texture it if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, it's really strange they haven't implemented that since the possibilities of what people could make with custom crafting supporting NBT data would be endless.  But I guess this workaround is better than nothing.

Comment: So to be honest I ran across this problem and decided that adding a mechanism to 'summon' the items was much easier. Maybe make a certain structure they have to build and they throw the items onto it, which gives them the item. I know this isn't an answer but just a suggestion for an alternate, easier, more infallible way. You could have them throw the items on top of a crafting table, or have them build a big crafting table with holes for the items to be thrown into.

Comment: In terms of the system I want to make for my adventure/survival map it's very important for the crafting to be contained in a small space since it will happen a lot.  It's also important since the player will be crafting a lot of custom tools, and the placement of the recipes for these tools in the crafting grid is very important.

Comment: You could also test for an e.g. dispenser or other inventory with certain items in it, maybe only make dispensers "crafting dispensers" if they have an armour stand on top, that makes it convenient for you to just do `at @e[type=armour_stand] if block ~ ~1 ~ dispenser{Items:[…]}`. And then replace the block with a dispenser with different items.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is a way to do it and no easy workaround either.

If it is possible for you to tag every sword, then you can use this to give a player a sword that does not have a custom name:

```
/give <player> minecraft:wooden_sword{canBeDeleted:true}
```

Which you then can delete with:

```
/clear @a minecraft:wooden_sword{canBeDeleted:true} 1
```

This would only delete swords with a "canBeDeleted" tag, so if you create a sword with a custom name without that tag, then it will not be affected.

Comment: The "canBeDeleted"-tag would be invisible to most players, they could find it by using /data and they can see how many tags there are if they have advanced tool tips enabled (toggle with F3+H)

Comment: The problem with this is that I am trying to make custom crafting using a datapack.  Since NBT data does not work for custom crafting I am using this clearing method as a workaround. I'm pretty sure canBeDeleted is NBT data, which would not work, since the outcome of the crafting recipe will simply be a wooden sword.

Comment: I would have to look into custom crafting. There does not seem to be a simple way where you do not check every slot one by one. It would be nice if there is a way to check if a certain tag is not set, but there does not seem to be a way to do that. There is an easy way to clear your inventory from custom named items though.

Comment: If you'd like to look into custom crafting I would suggest [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctY9ZmsoSqc) video, since this is what I used to get an understanding of how it works.  Basically, you can create custom recipes in JSON format, add them to a data pack, enable the data pack in game with `/datapack enable datapackname`.  The item that the recipe outputs can't have NBT data on it since it hasn't been implemented yet, which is why I am trying to use this workaround to it.

Comment: So basically what you want to do is to change the crafting recipee of the wooden sword in a way, so that the sword has a custom name?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  In the future, I will be using this system for more advanced NBT data like lore or custom coloured armour etc.  But as long as I can get this workaround operating correctly in terms of replacing non named items than I will be able to do this.

Comment: You could have them craft normally uncraftable items to get the specific item, like nether stars, spawn eggs, etc. Then, you keep track of how many they craft in a scoreboard and use recursion to give them a desired item and remove the crafted item until their score number has been lowered to 0.